# Type error in Haskell when creating reference

Tags: haskell

I am working on my homework and I am stuck at something.

```
> data Channel a = Chan { cap   :: Int 
>                       , queue :: [a]  }

> data FiniteChan a = IORef (Channel a)

> newFiniteChan :: Int -> IO (FiniteChan a)
> newFiniteChan capacity = do x <- newIORef (Chan {cap = capacity, queue = []})
>                             return x
```

Basically, I want to create a reference to `Channel a` when newFiniteChan is called and I want `FiniteChan a` to mean that reference (I can not change the signature of newFiniteChan). When I compile this, I get the following error:

```
final.lhs:235:38:
    Couldn't match expected type `FiniteChan a'
                with actual type `IORef (Channel a0)'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `x'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return x
    In the expression:
      do { x <- newIORef (Chan {cap = capacity, queue = []});
           return x }
```

I spent a lot of time figuring out the problem but I could not find. I appreciate any help.

Comment: `data FiniteChan a = IORef (Channel a)` declares a new type with a constructor `IORef`. I suspect you want to change it to `type FiniteChan a = ...`. (That would solve the type error, whether it is what you really want is a different question, but it looks so.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a constructor to the *FiniteChan* datatype, or turn it to a *type* alias instruction, this compiles:

```
import Data.IORef

data Channel a = Chan { cap   :: Int
                      , queue :: [a]  }

data FiniteChan a = FiniteChan (IORef (Channel a))

newFiniteChan :: Int -> IO (FiniteChan a)
newFiniteChan capacity = do
        x <- newIORef (Chan {cap = capacity, queue = []})
        return $ FiniteChan  x
```